# отправка почты средством php mail()

Tags: php, php7

здравствуйте, до обновления php с 5 на 7 версию функция mail() отправляла письма без ошибок, после того как я установил php7,  var_dump(mail(здесь параметры)) возвращает false, и письмо не отправляется, а так же не выводятся никакие ошибки, кроме php никаких дополнительных пакетов для отправки писем на машине не установлено

как я могу решить данную проблему? мне необходимо настроить обычную отправку писем, для того чтобы пользователи моего сайта могли сбрасывать пароли, никаких дополнительных приемов входящих писем и тд. мне не нужно

Comment: поищите разницу в конфигах пхп старой и новой версии там хранятся настройки сервера для отправки.